# Itk calculation of transformation matrix to allign two objects

Tags: c++, coordinate-transformation, itk

What is a correct way to calculate transformation matrix for itk's centered affine transform? I have vector for translation and directional cosines, but i am not able to get correct results (aligned axes rotations do not match). I am using itk's centered affine transform's function Rotate and feed in directional cosines in respect to each axes.

the transcription of code would then be:

```
itk::imageType::PointType angle_vector, PointA, PointB;

angle_vector[0]= atan((PointA[1] - PointB[1])/ (PointA[0] - PointB[0]));
angle_vector[1]= atan((PointA[0] - PointB[0])/ (PointA[1] - PointB[1]));
angle_vector[2]= atan((PointA[1] - PointB[1])/ (PointA[2] - PointB[2]));

itk::centeredAffineTransformation::Pointer transf = itk::centeredAffineTransformation::New();

transf->Rotate(0,1,angle_vector[0]);
transf->Rotate(0,2,angle_vector[1]);
transf->Rotate(1,2,angle_vector[2]);
transf->SetCenter(PointA);
```

and so on, with using filters utilizing tranformation